# Issue while adding maven dependency

Tags: maven

I am new to Maven and have been trying to configure an existing web project to Maven project.

I am getting the below error on adding hibernate dependencies.

```
**cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'dependency'. One of '{"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":parent, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":name, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/
 4.0.0":description, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":url, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":prerequisites, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":issueManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":ciManagement, 
 "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":inceptionYear, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":mailingLists, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":developers, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":contributors, "http://
 maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":licenses, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":scm, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":organization, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":build, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":profiles, 
 "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":modules, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":repositories, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":pluginRepositories, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":dependencies, "http://
 maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":reports, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":reporting, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":dependencyManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":distributionManagement, "http://
 maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":properties}' is expected.**
```

The pom.xml is as below -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Adore_india</groupId>
  <artifactId>Adore_india</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: If its an existing web project, you can directly generate a pom by converting it to a maven project. You may refer this post: http://crunchify.com/how-to-convert-existing-java-project-to-maven-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `<dependency>` tag must be a child of `<dependencies>`
so add `<dependencies>` and `</dependencies>` arround it

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Adore_india</groupId>
  <artifactId>Adore_india</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  ...
```